# Images jump up on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If you take a look at [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dRyGL/) you'll know what I am talking about. I'm trying to create the effect that when the user hovers over one of the images, he gets that remove bar sliding down from the image. 
 Problem is, when I hover over an image, the other images jump down from some strange reason. 
HTML:

```
<div class="show">
    <a href="#">
        <img alt="Pic1" class="thumbnail" />
    </a>
    <div class="remove-bar">
        <a href="#">r </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show">
    <a href="#">
        <img alt="Pic2" class="thumbnail" />
    </a>
    <div class="remove-bar">
        <a href="#"> r</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="show">
    <a href="#">
        <img alt="Pic3" class="thumbnail" />
    </a>
    <div class="remove-bar">
        <a href="#">r</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
.thumbnail {
  width: 12.5em;
  height: 18.750em;
  margin: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px lighten(#333, 30%);
}
.remove-bar {
  text-align: right;
  width: 11.9em ;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
    } .remove-bar a {
    color: white;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.remove-bar').hide();
$('.show a').hover(function() {
    $(this).next('div.remove-bar').slideDown(100);
}, function() {
    $(this).next('div.remove-bar').slideUp(100);
});
```

Also, notice that when you hover over an image and try to click 'r', you can't because it quickly disappears. **Thanks a lot!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your `.show` items `display:inline-block;`. By default their `vertical-align` is initially set to `baseline`. **[See MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)**

If you set your `.show`'s style to include `vertical-align:top;` this will alleviate the issue.

**[Fixed Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dRyGL/3/)**

Comment: +1 for the reason. Also, the second question of the Op can be solved by binding the hover on the wrapper `div` instead of `a`. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/dRyGL/6/

Comment: thanks @abhitalks i didnt see the second part of the question

Comment: Thanks to both of you! That's just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position: absolute` in  `remove-bar` class

```
.remove-bar {
  text-align: right;
  width: 11.9em ;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 1em;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

And `position: relative` in parent div class

```
.show {
  display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dRyGL/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS3 for this instead of JavaScript! Also, you should use `vertical-align:top;` for the top-level element.

```
.show {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.show a + div {
    height: 0px;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
.show a:hover + div {
    height: auto;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

No JS! http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/Smwd6/

Comment: It should be like this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Smwd6/2/ to solve the second part of Op's query as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party, but here's a Fiddle that solves your jQuery issue. Play with the settings to get it just right.

http://jsfiddle.net/dRyGL/25/

```
$('.remove-bar').hide();
var bar = null;
$('.show a').hover(function() {
    bar = $(this).next('div');
    bar.slideDown(100);
}, function() {
    setTimeout( function(){      
        if(bar.is(":hover")){
        }else{
            bar.slideUp(100);
        }
    },400);//give slow folks 200ms to get to the bar element
});

$('.remove-bar').hover(function(){
    }, function(){
    $(this).slideUp(100);
    }
);

$(document).mousemove(function() {
    setTimeout( function() {
        $('.remove-bar').each(function() {
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            if($(this).is(':hover')) {
            }else{
                if(parent.is(':hover') === false)
                {
                   $(this).slideUp(100);
                }
            }
        });
    },400);
});
```

I tried to cover all the edge cases which could leave to a `remove-bar` div being erroneously left open.

Comment: my apologies halfer, i didn't realize i had requested an upvote. not sure what i was thinking. please accept my sincere apology.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `float:left` to your `.show` class, the problem can be rectified.